# System.out.printf with decimal coordinates and multiple text

Tags: java, printf

I have been searching through here and can't seem to find what might assist me to fix my code.

I am trying to have the output pring (2.0, 2.0) when user enters 2 and 2.  I commented out the code that I need help with.  I am suppose to use printf to get my outcome.  I get nothing but errors.
It is my assumption that the issue lies in where I have to print the (2.0, 2.0) between text, however I am unable to solve my errors.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class prtest {

    // checks to see if radom point entered by user is within rectangle
    // rectangle is centered at (0,0) and has a width of 10 and height of 5

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter a point with two coordinates: ");
        int x = input.nextInt();
        int y = input.nextInt();

        double hDistance = Math.pow(x * x, 0.5f);// heigth distance

        double vDistance = Math.pow(y * y, 0.5f);// vertical distance

        if ((hDistance <= 10 / 2) && (vDistance <= 5.0 / 2))

            System.out
                    .print("Point (" + x + ", " + y + ") is in the rectangle");

        // System.out.printf("Point ( %1f", ", " + y + ") is in the rectangle");

        else
            System.out.print("Point (" + x + ", " + y
                    + ") is not in the rectangle");

        // System.out.printf("Point ( %1f", ", " + y +
        // ") is not in the rectangle");

    }// end main
}// end prtest
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the `System.out.printf` method in the wrong way. Your method should work using it like this:

```
System.out.printf("Point (%.1f, %.1f) is in the rectangle", x*1.0, y*1.0);
//...
System.out.printf("Point (%.1f, %.1f) is not in the rectangle", x*1.0, y*1.0);
```

Or even better, you can handle the point as integers

```
System.out.printf("Point (%d, %d) is in the rectangle", x, y);
//...
System.out.printf("Point (%d, %d) is not in the rectangle", x, y);
```

More info to understand the usage og `System.out.printf`: [Format String Syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax)

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work for me.

System.out.printf("Point , ('%1.1f', '%1.1f') is in the rectangle", (double) x, (double) y);